# Failing on creating files in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a file or directory in android by the the code below, but its always results "Directory not created".

The first method returning "true" which means the external storage is available.

I'v tried every examples and commands in the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) and all of them didn't work.

Also, I included the permission in the Manifests as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The code is:

```
public void createWorkbook(String fileName){
        boolean CheckSDcard = isExternalStorageWritable();
        if (!CheckSDcard){
            Toast.makeText(ReportsPage.this, "SDCard not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        getStorageDir(fileName);
    }

    public File getStorageDir(String FileName) {

        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), FileName);
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
        }
        return file;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Note: the emulator is "Nexus 5" and the version of the software is 7.0 "Nougat".

Its a bit confusing because almost all the commands working fine and returning the requested path but when creating the file and checking it by "mkdirs() or mkdir()" its returning false and the URI is "NULL".

Moreover, I checked the app on a real device "HUAWEI Mate 8" with Android version 6.0, and its giving the same results.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `if (!file.mkdirs()) `. Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist. If mkdirs fails you should return `null` so the calling app knows that it is not there. Please adapt your code.

Comment: `void createWorkbook`. Void? Make it a boolean function which tells you if you have a directory or not.

Comment: mkdirs() only returns true if the directory was created by the command.  I would write a separate check to see whether it actually exists.  Are you sure the directory doesn't exist?

Comment: You asked the user for runtime permissions to write to external memory?

Comment: Now, I used 'File isExist = getStorageDir(fileName);
        String path = isExist.getPath();
        Toast.makeText(ReportsPage.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();' to check the path of the file. Its returned "storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packageName/files/Download/newfile"' but when checking by the uri it gives null.

Comment: @SteveSmith I am sure the directory is not created, but as greenapps mentioned its may be coused because of the run-time permission, so I will try to grant the permission by the user.

Comment: I would replace the line `if (!file.mkdirs()) {` with `if (!file.exists()) {`

Comment: @SteveSmith , Using "if (file.exists())" returned true. But when checking the Download directory its empty.

Comment: if `file.exists()` return true, it can only mean it exists.  Try file.`canRead()`.  How are you checking the Download directory?

Comment: Using (getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename) returning "Not exists " and can't be read, However if I used 'getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)' everything working fine and 'canRead()' returning true. I am quite beginner for this, my app is for saving all the furniture of a company in sqlite DB and generate QR-code for each. Now I did every thing but I need to create excel files in order to send the info. via Bluetooth or Emails. However, I am using ES file explorer to check it.

Comment: And when checking it on real phone, its not working on both cases :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add runtime permission for android 6 or above

```
//try adding this code on activity creation 
 int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }

//method hasPermissions for checking if already has permission

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: As a test, check that the `Storage` permission is disabled in the `Settings > Apps > your-app > Permissions` and simply switch it on with the above code disabled to determine if it was the permission.

Comment: thank you, I'v tried your code and accepted the permission. Also, I used "if (file.exists())" and its returning true. But the Download directory is empty. How should I found the created file?

Comment: @WissamAl-Kindy give your file some extension first...and use some file manager to check if file exists at this path... storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packageName/files/Download/‌​newfile

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker , finally its worked. I changed the API to 23 instead of 24 and every thing worked perfectly. However, its not a proper solution and I think there was an issue in the API24 files. +1 for granting the permission.